# Theorem, corollary, equation numbering in amsbook

Tags: numbering, amsbook

I am using the `amsbook` class and `amsthm` package as follows :

```
\theoremstyle{plain} %% This is the default, anyway
\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}[equation]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[equation]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[equation]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[equation]{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[equation]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[equation]{Example}
\newtheorem{exer}[equation]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{notation}[equation]{Notation}
\newtheorem{terminology}[equation]{Terminology}
%etc
```

and I would like all theorems, corollaries etc being numbered as

- partnumber.chapternumber when they are inside a chapter and not in any section, subsection or "lower-level" sub-subs-...-subsections
- partnumber.chapternumber.sectionnumber when they are inside a section and not in any subsection, subsection or "lower-level" sub-subs-...-subsections
- etc

I would like the same for equations but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, don't reset chapter numbers with parts; you should also think twice before bothering your readers with this complicated numbering scheme.

```latex
\documentclass[openany]{amsbook}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem} % one suffices for the example
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsubsection}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{%
  \printuptozero{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}{equation}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printuptozero}{mm}
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \ujs_printuptozero:n
  \arabic{#2}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \ujs_printuptozero:n
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \value{#1}>0 } { \arabic{#1}. } { \clist_map_break: }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\begin{thm}
test
\end{thm}

\begin{equation}
0=0
\end{equation}

\section{Test}

\begin{thm}
test
\end{thm}

\begin{equation}
0=0
\end{equation}

\subsection{Test}

\begin{thm}
test
\end{thm}

\begin{equation}
0=0
\end{equation}

\subsection{Test}

\begin{thm}
test
\end{thm}

\begin{equation}
0=0
\end{equation}

\chapter{Test}

\begin{thm}
test
\end{thm}

\begin{equation}
0=0
\end{equation}

\section{Test}

\begin{thm}
test
\end{thm}

\begin{equation}
0=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

With `\counterwithin*{equation}{subsubsection}` we subordinate `equation` to every section level including and above `subsubsection`.

Next I redefine `\theequation` to scan successively the value of the sectional counters; if the value is positive, the number and a period are printed; otherwise the loop is stopped. At the end the value of `equation` is printed.

The `openany` option has been used just to make the example fit in two pages and have a single picture of the output.

[image]